# Handle concurrent updates Spring Boot JPA, get next db entry

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, concurrency, optimistic-locking

I have to reserve the next available Testuser from the DB.
For this, I have a query that fetches the first row from all available TestUsers.

Since this is triggered by entering a request on the front-end part, it could happen that the same TestUser is being reserved at the same time. If so, I would like to fetch the next available one again.

I've looked into OptimisticLocking, but I get the error that version column doesn't exist (and I DO have a version table of type int in the db, and have set all the values to 1)
I don't care about using this mechanism or another, I want the best way to solve this problem. Can anybody direct me?

Below the implementation I tried, and got the invalid column 'version' exception:

```
private void reserveTestUserId(String environment, Long id){
    int retryCounter = 0;
    
    while (retryCounter < 3){
        logger.info("############This is try number {}", retryCounter);
        try {
            TestUserIdMasterData testUser = this.myUserIdRepository.getFirstAvailableTestUserIdInEnvironment(environment);
            testUser.setReservedForRequestid(id);
            
            //testing lock
            testUser.setVersion(2);
            
            this.testUserIdMasterDataRepository.saveAndFlush(testUser);
            retryCounter = 999;
        } catch (OptimisticLockException ex){
            retryCounter++;
        }
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name=......, schema=.......)
public class TestUserIdMasterData {

/** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Version
@Column(name="version")
private int version;
.......
```

Comment: is your `reserveTestUserId` method running inside an UnitTest ?

Comment: @AlexCiocan no it isn't.. I'm testing in dev environment, simply added setVersion inside loop to try and generate error